# how to allocate memory of a struct variable

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am struggling to figure out how to allocate memory for my `studentContent` variable.

```
struct contactInfo {
    char  Name[101];
    char  Assignment[101];
    char  MarkDescription[101];
    char feedBack[12][101];

};
struct contactInfo studentContent
```

I want to use `malloc()` to allocate memory for my structure variable. After the structure is filled I would like to reallocate the memory so I am only utilizing as much space within each field as I need to.

Comment: Why are you allocating space for 2 structs? And what do you mean when you say the size of the contents will be different? How so?

Comment: sorry maybe i made a mistake. I want to allocate space for 1 struct. The contents will be different each time i loop. I am looping through a file pulling each line a storing each line in its respected field within the struct. After i have filled all the fields i write to a file those contents in a different order. my loop will then continue reading the file and store the next set of data into the struct so the fields may differ in size the second time around.

Comment: You cannot change the size of the elements in the struct. They will always be the size they were declared as. If the strings you read into those arrays are less then the size of the array, that's fine. You don't need to do anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first assignment sets `ptr` to the address of the local variable `studentContent`, however the next line overwrites that.  It changes `ptr` to point to a dynamically allocated buffer with space for 2 instances of `struct contactInfo`.

If what you want is to have an **array** of `struct contactInfo`, and have the number of elements of that array increase as you have more instances of `struct contactInfo` to populate, you pass `ptr` to `realloc` with a size of `n * sizeof *ptr`, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.

```
struct contactInfo *tmp_ptr = realloc(ptr, n * sizeof *ptr);
if (tmp_ptr == NULL) {
    perror("realloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
ptr = tmp_ptr;
```

Note that you don't have to declare an instance of `struct contactInfo` (`studentContent` in your original code), just a pointer to one.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, since you just need a single instance to populate in order to read and write one chuck of data at a time, you don't need to use dynamic memory allocation.  Just declare a single instance and overwrite the contents each time.

Comment: I know i don't necessary need it but would if one of my fields is a char array[101] that is only filled half way. I want to make that field slim down to the exact size needed. I only want to take up as much space as i need to. For practice sake.

Comment: I'm not there yet and it is probably a separate question, but i want to make all my fields pointers so that i can just point to one char [101] if that is possible.

Comment: if i fill it with data up to [50] id like to only have to use up to [50] . Does that make sense?

Comment: I have edited the question to just try and figure out first how to allocate memory for my studentContent variable.

Comment: @bodotheguy You don't need to allocate any memory.  Just define an instance of the struct like you're doing.  If that doesn't meet your needs, explain *why* it doesn't (preferably with code) and what might.

Comment: You are right, i need to re-think what i am truly trying to ask. I will do so and ask again after i try a few things.